# change orientation of ray sensor

Tags: ros, laser, gazebo-plugins, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with the ray sensor plugin for Gazebo, such as the one used by a Hokuyo laser range finder. I'm having trouble getting it in the right orientation for my robot. I've tried to orientate the joint that the sensor plugin is attached to as well as use the xml origin tags included in the plugin but nothing has produced a different orientation.

After playing with the results, I noticed the rays are always in +x direction relative to the frame of the sensor. I'm actually wanting to pitch the ray sensor by 90 degrees.

Has anyone been able to change the orientation? Or even easier, change the axis on which to read laser scans?

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12223/change-orientation-of-ray-sensor/) by [seth_g](https://answers.ros.org/users/1153/seth_g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you pitch the link that the sensor is attached to (instead of the joint), it will pitch.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seth_g](https://answers.ros.org/users/1153/seth_g/) on 2011-12-05**:
hmm... I don't know why I didn't think to do that. Good catch.

**Comment by [vijay.v](https://answers.ros.org/users/30326/vijay.v/) on 2018-11-08**:
Hi, I gave the pitch to the link where ray sensor is present and visualize the point cloud output in RVIZ, I am still getting wrong output... I suspect that output was with respect to some other frame not with respect to sensor frame.
actually, I need lidar with pitch 90 deg like top view need help.